# Photoshop CC 2019: Pixelated Brush Stroke

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

For some reasons my brush stroke suddenly looks like this:

[image]

As the picture showed, the edges are jagged and pixelated. It doesn't happen before and it's just one of the built-in inking brush.

I know there are a lot of similar questions here but please don't mark this as duplicate. I double checked all the thing the other answers suggested: It's brush tool, not pencil, and my mode of brush and layer is Normal, not Dissolve. It's pixelated even if I draw with mouse so it's not tablet driver issue. I disabled GPU render but nothing changed. How do I fix this?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  I can't replicate the problem. What is your OS, what kind of display - High res, or regular?  Is there any system zoom set? Mac? PC?  When you say "It doesn't happen before", do you mean it has never happened before? Are your graphics drivers up to date?   These are all just guesses. I don't know if this can be answered without access to your computer. If you suspect it's a bug, perhaps contact Adobe.

Comment: Show the brush settings please (from f5 menu): maybe you have a texture in there?

Answer (score 2):

This probably happens because you're working at a zoom of more than 100%. Working on larger canvases could help you avoid exceeding that zoom level.

An even better solution would be to use a vector editor, where the quality of graphics is independent from its size or zoom level.

The most popular vector graphics programs are Illustrator, CorelDRAW and Inkscape.

Comment: I just checked and it's zoomed to 100%